# Not able to open website in google colab using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-colaboratory, kora

I am trying to open website website in google colab using selenium but not able to do so. Installing chrome driver and setting path variable had issues, so I used Kora library. I am able to to execute wd.get('website') successfully and able to print source_code as well. Kindly let me know how to open website. Below is my code

```
!pip install kora -q
from kora.selenium import wd
wd.get('https://www.google.com')
wd.page_source
```

Comment: you can use bs4 if you only need scrap the content

Comment: yes I need to scrap only. I tired bs4 but not getting what I want. Using bs4 I tried to scrap linkedIn search result link but I am not getting links and tags of profiles as shown below. I thought may be it is because of login issue using python     ........................................from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
html = urlopen('https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=business%20analyst%20AND%20Mumbai&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER')
bso = soup(html.read())
bso..

Answer (score 0):

You can show the screen by display the `wd`.

```
display(wd)
```

What exactly do you want to do?